# using of http:conduit with https4 apache camel

Tags: ssl, apache-camel

Is it possible to use http:conduit element together with https4 element in Apache Camel ?

I have found only examples to use conduit together with CXF.

This is what i would like to use :

```
  <http:conduit name="{http://www.company.com/product/orderEntry/service/1}OrderEntry.http-conduit">
<http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
  <sec:trustManagers>
    <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${trustStore.password}" file="${trustStore.file}"/>
  </sec:trustManagers>
  <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
    <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
  </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
</http:tlsClientParameters>
```

How Apache Camel knows where to bind http:conduit information ? Which source class should I check ?

Thanks for all comments

Comment: Also posted at Camel mailing list - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/using-http-conduit-without-CXF-tp5733744.html

Comment: Interesting discussion I have found here : http://fusesource.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=15877 would prove that at this stage http:conduit is CXF specific component and can't be easily integrated with other components.

Comment: Okay can you mark your question as answered, as its not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment. This is not possible (see discussion : http://fusesource.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=15877). Here (http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-UsingtheJSSEConfigurationUtility) one can find instruction about https4 and SSL